# How to hide icons from System Settings?

Tags: 12.04

I installed Ubuntu Tweak and noticed an icon for it in System Settings. Is it possible to hide the icon?

Answer (score 2):

It can be done by modifying the `/usr/share/applications/ubuntu-tweak.desktop`.

Open `ubuntu-tweak.desktop` in your favorite editor:

```
gksu gedit /usr/share/applications/ubuntu-tweak.desktop
```

Under `[Desktop Entry]` remove "Settings;" from `Categories` line.

Afterwards run:

```
sudo update-desktop-database
```

That's it!

Comment: @Bjoswald On the answer that solved your question, hit the accept button under the voting points. To make it easier for future visitors to find a working answer.